# Is it possible to have a full Monero node, a Monero testnet node, and an Aeon node all on the same VPS?

Tags: full-node, aeon, testnet

I recently came across a great VPS deal (2 cores, 2GB RAM, 100GB SSD) and was wondering if its possible to install all three nodes on the same server? I don't know a lot about networking though. Will the ports clash or something? Are there any extra settings that would help with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aeon has not yet integrated LMDB so the 2GB RAM is probably not enough. Although it should work (slower) if the swap is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

They should all be operating on different ports so yes, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And thats 18080 for Monero, 28080 for testnet, and 11181 for Aeon?

Comment: Pretty sure that's right.

Comment: 11180 for aeon. *81 are used for rpc bind port

Comment: @moroccan engineer: that's what I originally thought but the web says otherwise.